# Online - Get thumbnail in search results

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search, search-results

I'm using SharePoint Online and I've a CEWP where I call SharePoint search API.

In this call I'm using a query template because I want to retrieve only .mp4 files. In my document library I've also a "`Thumbnail`" column (picture) which automatically shows thumbnail of the video.

I'm trying to get this column in my search results, so I can show thumbnails in my CEWP. I've also take a look to the OOB SharePoint search results and I can see that the thumbnail of the video is correctly shown.

How can I have the Thumbnail column in my search result dataset?

Comment: @Pepozozo Any solution??